# PDF file sometime being displayed as garbage

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, ashx, filehandler

I am having a user who is reporting that files are being displayed as raw data in his browser. He uses Internet Explorer.

The files are being served via a .ashx handler file and it has been working until.

This is the relevant part of my .ashx handler:

```
context.Response.Clear()
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name)
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", size.ToString)
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
context.Response.TransmitFile(fullname)
context.Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Can anyone figure something out of this screenshot?
[image]

Update: this behaviour appears on Windows 10 when running either IE 11 or Edge and only the second time a file is being opened. It happens for both .pdf and .docx files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself - it had to do with the HTTP header `content-length` which i mistakenly submitted with a value exactly 1byte too large.

This caused the strange behavior in only IE/Edge and only Windows 10 as described in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use to stream PDFs to a client. It works in IE 11. The main difference is that I am using BinaryWrite which based on your code, you may not want to do..

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

[There might be a solution here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1036628.aspx?Problem%20Streaming%20PDF%20File%20to%20IE%20Browsers)

[I'll like this as well just in case..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231239/response-transmitfile-corrupting-file)

According to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a56a83c-6782-496e-a749-46f852545281/using-aspnet-pdf-file-downloading-is-not-working-in-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment), it could be as simple as replacing `Response.Close` with `Response.End` (or in your case.. adding)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an aspx page that transmits file to browser in Page_Load event handler.
My mistake was an absense of

```
Response.End();
```

method call. When I added this line the problem has gone.